# how to ignore file "hand-" not "hand_" prefix?

Tags: mercurial

In the repository, there is a directory named like "`hand-0.0.1.1`" and there is a source file named like "`hand_soldier.erl`". 
I want to ignore hand-0.0.1.1 directory and keep "hand_soldier.erl".

In the sourcetree's repository ignore file, I have tried to write:

```
hand\-*
```

and

```
hand-*
```

but both not work.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may want to know that you can always explicitly add files that are in the ignore list and they will be tracked. `.hgignore` only operates on non-tracked files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add just `hand-` in ignore file.

For me it works good:

```
hg init
touch hand_soldier.erl
mkdir hand-0.1
touch hand-0.1/file.txt
echo 'hand-' > .hgignore
hg status
? .hgignore
? hand_soldier.erl
```